# Spring 3 SAMLProcessingFilter authenticationManager must be specified

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

I want to create a new application with spring boot version 3 and Java 17 with SAML2 token authentication. While writting SecurityConfig class, since it cannot extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class in Spring 3, I do not know how to supply authenticationManager in SAMLProcessingFilter to supply in FilterChainProxy. My SecurityConfig class is below code line:

samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(???);

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${saml.sp}")
    private String samlAudience;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("saml")
    private SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler samlAuthSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("saml")
    private SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler samlAuthFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private SAMLLogoutFilter samlLogoutFilter;

    @Autowired
    private SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter samlLogoutProcessingFilter;

    @Autowired
    private HttpSecurity httpSecurity;

    @Bean
    public SAMLDiscovery samlDiscovery() {
        SAMLDiscovery idpDiscovery = new SAMLDiscovery();
        return idpDiscovery;
    }

    @Autowired
    private SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata;

    @Autowired
    private KeyManager keyManager;

    public MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator() {
        MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator = new MetadataGenerator();
        metadataGenerator.setEntityId(samlAudience);
        metadataGenerator.setExtendedMetadata(extendedMetadata);
        metadataGenerator.setIncludeDiscoveryExtension(false);
        metadataGenerator.setKeyManager(keyManager);
        return metadataGenerator;
    }

    @Bean
    public SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter = new SAMLProcessingFilter();
        //AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);
        //**What should I give in below line**
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(samlAuthSuccessHandler);
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(samlAuthFailureHandler);
        return samlWebSSOProcessingFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterChainProxy samlFilter(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        List<SecurityFilterChain> chains = new ArrayList<>();
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSO/**"),
            samlWebSSOProcessingFilter(http)));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/discovery/**"),
            samlDiscovery()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/login/**"),
            samlEntryPoint));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/logout/**"),
            samlLogoutFilter));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SingleLogout/**"),
            samlLogoutProcessingFilter));
        return new FilterChainProxy(chains);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public MetadataGeneratorFilter metadataGeneratorFilter() {
        return new MetadataGeneratorFilter(metadataGenerator());
    }

    //@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf()
        .disable();

        http
        .httpBasic()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint);

        http
        .addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(samlFilter(http), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(samlFilter(http), CsrfFilter.class);

        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http
        .logout()
        .addLogoutHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
            try {
                response.sendRedirect("/saml/logout");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    @Bean
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the old Spring Security SAML Extension project. This project reached its [end of life](https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-security-saml#maintenance-mode) on October 6th, 2021, therefore it won't support Spring 6 which was released in November 2022.

The SAML support has been moved into Spring Security, you can refer to [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/index.html) in order to get started.

Comment: Can you guide me to a working example of Spring Boot 3 + Saml2 code implementation?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/saml2

Comment: @VISHALANAND Are you managed to implement SAML in spring 3 ?

Comment: Has anyone implemented it for KeyCloak SAML, any references would be appreciated.