# SAML2 Implementation with Spring Boot Version 3.X and Java 17

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, saml, saml-2.0

I am upgrading the current Spring Security SAML extension project to SAML2 authentication. I found a question where my sample existing security configuration looks like [Existing Security Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75383326/spring-3-samlprocessingfilter-authenticationmanager-must-be-specified).

There is an official documentation from Spring which is mentioned in the answer. But, I would like to better understand which part of code is getting replaced by which part in the new implementation with some working examples.

Kindly please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-security-saml-test-identity-provider-and-service-provider check this out. I've implemented SP initiated SSO flow with Spring Boot 3.

Comment: @gtiwari333 - your implementation will not fit into the versions I have mentioned. WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is no longer supported from Spring Security versions 6.0 (minimum spring security version used by Spring Boot version 3.X)..

Comment: i've three projects using different versions of spring boot. https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-security-saml-test-identity-provider-and-service-provider/blob/master/service-provider-sb3/src/main/java/g/t/saml/config/MySamlRelyingPartyConfiguration.java uses latest spring boot. did you check it out?